# How to improve a Tesla coil?

Tags: transformer, coil, resonance, tesla-coil

I've recently built a relatively big Tesla coil. It is a larger version of the Slayer exciter but with 2 big MOSFETs. The same circuit, with a smaller coil produced small arcs without a top load, and bigger arcs with a top load. My problem is that, with a larger secondary coil, the circuit produces large arcs without a top load, but when I add a top load, it gets overloaded and the arcs get very small. Can I solve this problem by making the secondary coil shorter? It is quite long.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an impedance matching issue. How do you power it? What’s your primary and secondary inductance and what’s your secondary capacitance?

Comment: I power it using DC from a full bridge rectifier and a 555 timer interrupter. I can't really measure the capacitance and inductance. I don't have the tools. I can only roughly calculate it.

Comment: What’s your calculated values? Schematic of your 555 based power stage?

Comment: My calculated inductance is 355uH.

Comment: Primary inductance? What about secondary inductance (assuming transformer type) and capacitance?

Comment: My secondary inductance is 355uH and my primary inductance is 2.1uH

Comment: 2/5 critical variables to simulate this are now given. Missing are capacitance, switching frequency and coupling factor/leakage inductance.

Comment: Ok. Can you please explain more about calculating these because I'm 14 years old and this is my hobby. I'm not experienced and I don't have many tools for measurement.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. Very good that you take an interest in EE and Tesla coils especially! I fondly remember building my first in my senior year in collage. Some people are very fluent in doing and experimenting without simulations, Tesla himself to mention someone. In 2022 and with MOSFETs actually frying, simulation with free tools is the way to go to build understanding and help in troubleshooting. In order to simulate your Tesla coil, you need values for several things. The (top) capacitance can be calculated from the diameter of it and distance to gound (floor). Frequency is what you set

Comment: your 555 to do. Leakage inductance can be estimated but if you have one of those 10 USD inductance testers, you can attach it to your primary coil and short the secondary with a cable. Should give you very accurate results. If you don't have one, I'll happily PayPal you the money for it.

Comment: That is extremely kind of you, but I can't accept it, you are helping me a lot with the simulation!

Comment: The frequency of my 555 timer circuit is 1Hz, the diameter of the top load is 19.5 cm   and it is at a height of 61 cm.

Comment: Can you help me with the simulation? Or if I can do it myself, I will (just tell me how).

Comment: Certainly! Too drunk at the moment but tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: Can you estimate the leakage inductance?

Comment: Kind reminder about simulation.

Comment: Haven't forgot about it. However, more information is needed. Is your top load a sphere? If yes, what's the radius of the toroid? Also, your primary circuit can be made in several different ways. Do you have a schematic or photo of yours?

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer in the making, please don't accept it yet.

This is not a discussion forum, and there is the risk of this question being closed as unclear, but let us cut you some slack and attempt to help you ask a specific question what is destroying your MOSFETs.

There are many many ways to make a Tesla coil, transformer based as yours, primaryless half-bridge, resonant tank, distributed resonant tank and so on. You need to provide a schematic of yours.

Here is an attempt:
[image]

Please install LTspice and create a schematic of yours. The coupling factor between the two coils, needs to be estimated or measured. You'll need to add your input voltage, exact make and model of MOSFET and so on.

Comment: My top load is a disks, also my MOSFETS are not dying. It's just that with a top load the sparks almost disappear. It works without a top load but the sparks are not very large.

Comment: I added a picture in the original question.

Comment: I am using a IRFP260N

Comment: Do you think a shorter coil would solve this issue?

Comment: Hello! I just wanted to let you know that I solved the issue. The coil was too long and the circuit couldn't drive it. You helped me a lot!  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!